# Is there a way to make list insert & list pop in def function?

Tags: python, list, insert

I want to make a **def function that have same effect with list insert and list pop.**

First, List insert have no return value. I make a def list_insert.

```
def list_insert(lst, index, obj, /):

lst = [1, 2, 3]
lst_insert(lst, 1, 6)
```

Second, List pop have return value. I make a def list_pop.

```
def list_pop(lst, index=-1, /):
    
lst = [1, 2, 3]
list_pop(lst, 1)
```

But I don't know how to unravel these method in def function.

Comment: You mean without using the existing methods `list.insert/pop`?

Comment: Yes, right! Except using list insert / pop method!

Comment: Please make your own attempt at such questions before asking. This feels like a homework question. While it's OK to ask for help with homework on SO, you should give it an honest try first and show where you get stuck. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3216427

Answer (score 0):

You could use slice assignment:

```
def list_insert(lst, index, obj, /):
    lst[index:index] = [obj]

lst = [1, 2, 3]
list_insert(lst, 1, 6)
lst
# [1, 6, 2, 3]

def list_pop(lst, index=-1, /):
    if 0 <= index < len(lst):
        lst[:] = lst[:index] + lst[index+1:]
    else:
        raise IndexError

lst = [1, 2, 3]
list_pop(lst, 1)
lst
# [1, 3]
```